# Getting INI configuration from /home/$USER/uwsgi.ini

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, logging, uwsgi

I am getting the following output while starting a uwsgi server:

```
$ uwsgi  --ini /home/aditya/uwsgi.ini

[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/aditya/uwsgi.ini
```

Is there a way to suppress/hide the above output without disabling uwsgi logging?